# Java two jvm update system, no jws or applet

Tags: java, swing, jar

I am currently working with Java 6, i cannot update. I cannot use Java Web Start or turn this desktop application into an applet. With that said, I am left with copying the new updated jar file from a share folder and pasting it into the users folder. I not a professional coder, I orignally code in Perl but for the past 6 months been working with Java. So you may see some issues, feel free to point them out. I love learning.

I have implemented the two JVM sessions just fine (i think). I am, however running into the following issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

I receive this error when the new Manifest version does not match the originally launched Manifest version. Once I kill the session (because it hangs after that error), and relaunch, it does detect the update and runs fine. Of course I cannot have the user go through that process.

This is how I am launching the second JVM once I have found that the versions do not match. I use this from the first application:

```
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Your version is outdated. I will try to update. Hold tight...", // Message
                    "Update Notice.", // Title
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                startSecondJVM();
                <ClassName>.MainWindow.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
```

Seems like it is not reaching the "System.exit(0)" portion. Do I need to implement threading or something?

This is the method its calling:

```
public static void startSecondJVM() throws Exception {
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String javapath = System.getProperty("java.home");
    //String javapath = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\";
    String fullJavaPath = javapath + "bin" + separator + "java";
    System.out.println("Java Path: " + fullJavaPath);
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = 
                new ProcessBuilder(fullJavaPath, "-jar", 
                    updatePath); //  AnotherClassWithMainMethod.class.getName()
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Once the second jar file that's in charge of updating launches. I have this in the main method of that file (with other code excluded of course):

```
 try {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      FileCopy.copyFile(FileCopy.source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The method its using is this:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
      if(!destFile.exists()) {
          destFile.createNewFile();
      }

      FileChannel source = null;
      FileChannel destination = null;

      try {
          source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
          destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
          destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());



      if(source != null) {
        source.close();
      }
      if(destination != null) {
          destination.close();
      }

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

    } // End of copy file
```

So to recap. The file copying process seems to work fine. The original application does not seem to completely quit though. After the copying process is complete, it proceeds to open. That is where I am running into the error. So my question is How can i completely kill the first application while i update with the second java app.

Comment: The file its downloading is located in a share drive. But it could be located in the next folder over. So I don't think that would make a difference. So i suppose the answer to that would be no.

Comment: For one, shared locations are slow (Coast to Coast in the U.S.). Second, there are chances of corrupting that file. Third if that file is in use i wont be able to update/delete/upgrade that file. Those are just some of the reasons i can think of which makes that suggestion a terrible idea. I think i elaborated in my first paragraph as to my requirements, restrictions, and expectations. Sadly I cannot control them, otherwise I could easily use JWS or drop it on an applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line in the first JAR:

```
process.waitFor();
```

This will wait until your second jar finishes running before the first JAR will quit - something you don't want (this is called a Deadlock).  You want to kick off the process and let it go.

I'm fairly confident if you remove this line, you should be fine.

Comment: Wow, amazing. How the heck did I miss that. You rock! After over 3,000 lines of code, this was the missing piece to finish this app. :D

Comment: :P  When you have 3k lines of code, it's easy to miss one.  I think we've all been there.